# Grant a user write access to bitbucket private repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repository `project1` in bitbucket which is private. I am using a free account. So I have 5 user limit. Now I share `project` to a user `bob` with *write* access so `bob` can *create branch*, *merge branch*.

But unfortunately I found `bob` can *create branch* **locally** but can not push it. Note none of me and `bob` is in a team. I just *shared* the repository with *write* access.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about setting up BitBucket permissions and not directly programming related.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you have to do is to **give "bob" "write" permission to your repository**. This can  be done in the "Access management" section of your BitBucket repo settings. More information can be found at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Repository+privacy%2C+permissions%2C+and+more